# Extract a dataframe from a list of dataframes containing a substring

Tags: pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have the following dataframes in python that are part of a list

```
dataframe_list= []## CREATE AN EMPTY LIST
import pandas as pd
A=pd.DataFrame()
A["name"]=["A", "A", "A"]
A["att"]=["New World", "Hello", "Big Day now"]
B=pd.DataFrame()
B["name"]=["A2", "A2", "A2"]
B["Col"]=["L", "B", "B"]
B["CC"]=["old", "Hello", "Big Day now"]
C=pd.DataFrame()
C["name"]=["Brave old World", "A", "A"]
```

The above dataframes are of different sizes. these are stored as a list as follows

```
 dataframe_list.append(A)
 dataframe_list.append(B)
 dataframe_list.append(C)
```

I am trying to extract two dataframes that contain the word world(irrespective of case). I have tried the following code

```
list1=["World"]
result=[x for x in dataframe_list if any(x.isin(list1) ) ]
```

This however is yielding all the dataframes. The expected output is dataframes A, C. Am not sure where I am making a mistake here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and test by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) by word `w` instead one element list, also is added words boundaries for match only whole words:

```
w="World"
result=[x for x in dataframe_list if x.stack().str.contains(rf"\b{w}\b", case=False).any()]
print (result)
[  name          att
0    A    New World
1    A        Hello
2    A  Big Day now,               name
0  Brave old World
1                A
2                A]
```

EDIT: For list of words is used `|` for regex or:

```
list1=["World",'Hello']
pat = '|'.join(rf"\b{x}\b" for x in list1)
result=[x for x in dataframe_list if x.stack().str.contains(pat, case=False).any()]
```

Comment: Thank you. Quick Question. Is it mandatory to split a string to match the small substring as done here

Comment: Thank you again. Is it possible to pass a list of words instead of a string as you have done

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs - Answer was edited. Also is added word bondaries here to both solutions. It means if `Brave old WorldNo` or `Brave old World1` it is no match, but `Brave old World` matching